# Pandas Comparison of NaN to nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe in Pandas that has columns A and B (there are more columns in my use)

```
A  | B
--------
C6   A2   
E9
     F3
```

I am doing a comparison to find a single row based on some given values from another dataframe (. (i.e. `df[(df.A == 'C6') & (df.B == 'A2')]` would return the first row.

This works great until I have to make comparison to NaN. I think the reason is because `np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`.

Is there a simple way to modify my code to make comparisons to strings or NaN without complicating the code?

Edit: Okay I don't think I explained this well. Given my above dataframe.. Given an input of 'E9' or nan in the same formula, I want it to return the corresponding row.

`df[df.A == 'E9']` returns the second row but `df[df.A == np.nan]` returns empty dataframe.

`pd.isna()` will help me only in the instance where input is `NaN`

Comment: `use `df['A'].isna()` to check for `np.nan` values.

Comment: @Bijan how is the result?

Comment: @Bijan try it again with your specific string

Comment: it will be not bad curning method

Comment: @QuangHoang `pd.isna()` will help me only in the instance where input is `NaN` but not if the input is a string

Comment: I don’t get it. Are you talking about the string `'NaN'` or the float `np.nan`?

Comment: Can you run `df.to_dict()` and paste that into your question so we can see _exactly_ what type of data is stored in the dataframe? Also can you include your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to match with empty string, since `np.nan == np.nan` returns `false`.

```
df[(df.A == 'C6')]
df[df.A == ""]
df[df.B == ""]
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0  C6  A9
```

```
  A   B
2    F3
```

```
  A   B
1 E9
```

Comment: This does not work for my use. `df[df.A == np.nan]` returns empty dataframe